# Как узнать имя переменной, которая отвечает за класс?

Tags: python-3.x, классы

Как можно сослаться на self другого массива?

```py
class Weapon:
    def __init__(self, name, damage, range):
        self.name, self.damage, self.range = name, damage, range

    def hit(self, actor, target):
        if target.is_alive():
            if ((actor.get_coords()[0] - target.get_coords()[0]) ** 2 +
                (actor.get_coords()[1] - target.get_coords()[1]) ** 2) ** 0.5 <= self.range:
                print(f'Врагу нанесен урон оружием {self.name} в размере {self.damage}')
                target.get_damage(self.damage)
            else:
                print(f"Враг слишком далеко для оружия {self.name}")
        else:
            print("Враг уже повержен")
```

Проблема заключается в том,что если я вызываю метод hit,то происходит ошибка,в которой говорится,что .get_coords() требует атрибут "self"

```py
    if ((actor.get_coords()[0] - target.get_coords()[0]) ** 2 +
TypeError: get_coords() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Однако, когда я подставляю этот атрибут self(то есть получается actor.get_coords(self)) то не работает уже вызов переменной self.range(Как я понял,питон пытается найти эту переменную в self`е вызываемого класса actor,и конечно не находит ее там)

```py
    (actor.get_coords(self)[1] - target.get_coords()[1]) ** 2) ** 0.5 <= self.range:
AttributeError: 'MainHero' object has no attribute 'range'
```

Определение actor`a:

```py
class MainHero(BaseCharacter):
    def __init__(self, pos_x, pos_y, name, hp):
        super().__init__(pos_x, pos_y, hp)
        self.name = name
        self.weapons, self.current_weapon = list(), ""
        self.count = 0

    def hit(self, target):
        if self.weapons:
            if type(target).__name__ == "BaseEnemy":
                Weapon.hit(self, MainHero, target)
            else:
                print("Могу ударить только Врага")
        else:
            print("Я безоружен")
```

Вот в этой строчке класса MainHero происходит вызов того метода hit класса Weapon:

```py
Weapon.hit(self, MainHero, target)
```

Так вот,как можно(если такое вообще допустимо) сослаться на переменную self класса переменной actor?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: а определение actor'a покажите

Comment: `class MainHero(BaseCharacter):
    def __init__(self, pos_x, pos_y, name, hp):
        super().__init__(pos_x, pos_y, hp)
        self.name = name
        self.weapons, self.current_weapon = list(), ""
        self.count = 0

    def hit(self, target):
        if self.weapons:
            if type(target).__name__ == "BaseEnemy":
                Weapon.hit(self, MainHero, target)
            else:
                print("Могу ударить только Врага")
        else:
            print("Я безоружен")`

Comment: а добавьте в вопрос. кнопка "править"

Comment: @PayAttention, не надо куски кода пихать в комментарии, они там ломаются. Добавьте в сам вопрос.

Comment: @Александр Да, извините, не знал

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ещё код строчки, где сама переменная actor создаётся. Ошибка почти наверняка в ней.

Answer (score 2):

Нам было бы гораздо проще отвечать, если бы написали, что такое вообще `actor` и как он создаётся.

В данной формулировке очевидно только одно: сейчас у вас в переменной `actor` лежит класс. А код ожидает там **экземпляр** данного класса.

То есть, скорее всего вам просто нужно там, где эта переменная создаётся заменить что-то подобное:

```
actor = Actor
```

на что-то подобное

```
actor = Actor()
```

В скобках, возможно, должны быть какие-то аргументы, но может и нет. В любом случае, сами скобки должны присутствовать.

Смысл в том, что `self` почти никогда не надо явно передавать при вызове метода. Если вы создали экземпляр класса, то в его методах `self` будет автоматически определятся.

Comment: В вопросе указал строчку где вызывается сам метод hit.При вызове этого метода обязательно запрашивает аргумент self

Comment: Вы неправильно понимаете смысл аргумента self и вообще суть классов. Нужно понимать разницу между самим классом и экземпляром этого класса. Вы в вашем коде создаёте классы которые явно предназначены для инстанцирования (это очевидно, по наличию метода init и методам с self), но при этом вы нигде не создаёте экземпляры. Рекомендую вам разобрать основы ООП на примерах попроще.

Comment: А если говорить конкретно про ваш код - то конечно метод hit будет запрашивать self, ведь в сигнатуре метода hit вы же сами указали self. Если вы хотите метод, который будет вызываться у класса, а не у экземпляра, и не запрашивать self, то вам нужно объявить этот метод либо статическим, либо методом класса, с помощью соответствующих декораторов. Но лучше всё-таки разберите тему классов и их объектов, и используйте ООП по назначению.

Comment: Видимо да,в любом случае спасибо за помощь,попробую разобраться